# Is a de-zeroed Hardy function still Hardy?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

Suppose a Hardy function $f(z)$ on the upper half complex plane or [$f\in H^{2+}$ (Chapter II, p.45 of Fulvio Ricci, Hardy Spaces in One Complex Variable)](http://homepage.sns.it/fricci/papers/hardy.pdf) has a zero of order $m$ at $\omega$ with $\mathbf{Im}(\omega)>0$. A Hardy $H^{2+}$ function $f(z=x+iy)$ on the upper half complex plane is a holomorphic function on the that plane where $f_y(x):=f(x+iy)\in L^2(\mathbf R)$ with norm $\|f_y\|_2$ with respect to $x$ for any given $y$, and $\sup_y\|f_y\|_2<\infty$. Is $\displaystyle\frac{f(z)-f(\omega)}{(z-\omega)^n}\in H^{2+},\, \forall n\le m$?

Comment: can you define Hardy plz

Comment: @mathworker21: Just added a reference. Check the chapter on the half plane.

Comment: I saw definitions depending on $p$. I still don't know what "Hardy" means. I'd appreciate you either giving a definition in the problem or telling me what page of the PDF to look at so that I don't waste more time scrolling

Comment: @mathworker21: Chapter II, p.45, $p=2$.

Comment: @Hans: I don't see any definition of "Hardy" on that page. The only occurrence of the word "Hardy" on page 45 is in the chapter title.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Well, $H^p$ is the Hardy space. I suppose the authour should have explicitly call out the name in words.

Comment: @Hans: In your question you're talking about a "Hardy _function_" rather than a "Hardy _space_".

Comment: @HenningMakholm: The element of a Hardy space, which is a set of functions, is a Hardy function. I specifically write $f\in H^{2+}$ to which the reference paper is linked in particular to in my question. There is no ambiguity there. Don't you think?

Comment: @Hans: It is certainly an ambiguity that you have phrased your question using a term that it took 8 comments to persuade you to define. Now edit your question to contain that definition such that future readers won't have to read through the comment thread to find out what you mean.

Comment: The document you link to _does not contain the words "Hardy function" next to each other_ even once!

Comment: @HenningMakholm: As I said, there is *no* ambiguity since every word is defined. I said "or $f\in H^2$ in the question. The paper defines perfectly well what  it means to be $H^p$. You are nitpicking on nothing. I have been very patient in answering all the enquiries. And what is "Now edit your ..."? Who gives you the authority to bark orders like an overlord? Where does the attitude come from?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: This is infuriating. You owe me an apology!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had I read further into [Fulvio Ricci, Hardy Spaces in One Complex Variable](http://homepage.sns.it/fricci/papers/hardy.pdf), Chapter II, Theorem 5.4 provides the answer. This theorem also appears as [Theorem 3.10 in Section 3, Chapter 20, of John B. Conway, Functions of One Complex Variable II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387944605), and Theorem 11.6 of [Peter L. Duren, Theory of $H^p$ Spaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486411842) regarding the [Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) factorization.

---

Edit: Actually, it is not necessary to use the explicit factorization as referred to above.

The answer is affirmative

Proof: Consider $n=1$. Larger $n\le m$ works the same.
$g(z):=\frac{f(z)-f(\omega)}{z-\omega}$ is holomorphic on the closed upper half complex plane. Let $D(\omega;R)$ be the closed disk centered at $\omega$ and radius $0<R<\mathbf{Im}(\omega)$. $|g(z)|$ has a maximum and is bounded on the compact $D(\omega,R)$.

For an arbitrary $y\ge0$, let $\Omega_y:=\{x+iy: x\in\mathbf R\}\setminus D(\omega;R)$. We have
$$|g(z)|\le \frac{|f(z)|}R+\frac{|f(\omega)|}{|z-\omega|},\ \forall |z-\omega|\ge R.$$
$|z-\omega|^2\ge(R^2+x^2)$, where $x$ is a real number such that $x+x_0=\mathbf{Re}(z-\omega)$ and that $|x_0+i\mathbf{Im}(z-\omega)|=R$.

By the Minkowski inequality
$$\Big(\int_{\Omega_y} |g(x+iy)|^2 dx\Big)^\frac12 \le \frac1R\Big(\int_{\Omega_y} |f(x+iy)|^2 dx\Big)^\frac12+|g(\omega)|\Big(2\int_0^\infty\frac1{R^2+x^2}dx\Big)^\frac12$$
The first integral on the right hand side is uniformly bounded over $y$ by the definition of $H^{2+}$. $\displaystyle 2\int_0^\infty\frac1{R^2+x^2}\,dx=\frac\pi R$. We are done. $\quad\square$

Comment: I don't quite see the irony here. Is it ironic that the very text you're reading contains information about the topics it presents?

Comment: @JohnHughes: Yes, indeed. I read a bit further into the paper I used as a reference in the question after I posted the question and found the factorization theorem I was looking for. However, now I think the theorem is unnecessary to prove the affirmative statement. What is your opinion?

Comment: @JohnHughes: I just posted my proof. Please review.